# Unable to resolve service for type 'AService' while attempting to activate 'BService'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am attemping to use an IHostedService from another IHostedService but am getting an error when I start my application. I would like to use AService from BService. I see there are other solutions but I am looking for a specific solution for .net-core 3.0.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'TwoHostedServices.AService' while attempting to activate
>   'TwoHostedServices.BService'.'

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServicesDelegate)
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }

        private static void ConfigureServicesDelegate(HostBuilderContext hostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<AService>()
                .AddHostedService<BService>();
        }
    }

    public class AService : IHostedService
    {
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class BService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly AService _aService;

        public BService(AService aService)
        {
            _aService = aService;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `AddHostedService` registers against `IHostedService`, not the concrete type ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/3.0/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs#L21)). You can work around that easily enough, but I expect it's somewhat unusual to have `IHostedService` implementations know about each other.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Your comment is the answer.